# How to make asynchronous web queries with callback in Julia?

Tags: asynchronous, web-scraping, julia

How to do the following in an async way in Julia:

the JavaScript-ish pseudo-code would be:

```
for i in 1:100
    asyncCall(get(webpageAddr[i]), callback(err, data){
        insertToDB(db, coll, data)
    })
end
```

I am interested in how the async part of the code should look like (no so much the web query and db access, I'll take care of those). The 100 queries can run independently (asynchronously) from one another and the rest of the Julia code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia prefers to write code in a synchronous way without losing the power of parallelism, so to speak. You do not have to think in terms of callbacks.

Below, you see `@async` macro, which runs task (coroutine) on the local process only and `@sync` macro to wait until all the enclosed tasks are done.

```
@sync begin 
    for i=1:10
        @async begin
            println("I mimic the get for $i"); # -> get(webpageAddr[i])
            sleep(rand(1:3)) #waiting for server answer at random number of seconds
            println("I mimic the callback for $i") # -> callback(err, data){insertToDB(db, coll, data}
        end
    end
end
```

I encouraged you to dig into the details of parallel computing in Julia, because these are enormous.

Comment: Really great answer. Thanks. I especially like how you mimic the time it takes the `get` with `sleep(rand)`, which makes it crystal clear how async works.